# Is it possible to have two "ServiceManifests" for a single ServiceManifest.xml file

Tags: c#, xml, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I was wondering if anyone may be able to assist with some questions I have regarding Azure Service Fabric's ServiceManifest.xml and ApplicationManifest.xml files.

##### Background

I am working with a multi service application in C# that relies on Azure Service Fabric's technology. We use an `ApplicationManifest.xml` file for our application at large, and a `ServiceManifest.xml` file for each individual service. Our ServiceManifest follows the following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="MyServiceName.ConfigurationServicePkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
         This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in Program.cs. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="MyServiceName.Configuration" >
     <PlacementConstraints>requestManagerAllowed==true</PlacementConstraints>
     </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>

  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>MyCompanyName.MyServiceName.Configuration.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value=""/>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </CodePackage>

  <!-- Config package is the contents of the Config directoy under PackageRoot that contains an 
       independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service. -->
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0"/>

</ServiceManifest>
```

Our services (and solution at large) were recently rebranded for a new environment we must deploy to, while still deploying to the old environment. We have edited all of our .csproj files to have two different assembly names depending on which Build Configuration we are targeting, so that we can build and publish the binaries for both the new and old environments.

For example, we have a **Configuration Service** in our application. When building using the old build configuration, the configuration service's exe would be named as follows `OldCompanyName.OldServiceName.Configuration.exe`

When building using the new build configuration, the name changes, and looks like `NewCompanyName.NewServiceName.Configuration.exe`

##### Problem

The issue is that we still need to be able to deploy to both the new and old environments. When trying to deploy our services to the new environment, Service Fabric uses the Configuration Service's `ServiceManifest.xml` to determine it needs to find the `OldCompanyName.OldServiceName.Configuration.exe` executable as the entry point for that service. However, our solution has to be built using the new build configuration, so all the exe's and dll's are named under the new convention `NewCompanyName.NewServiceName.Configuration.exe`.

Since it is unable to find the entry point for the service, Service fabric throws the following exception:

```
The EntryPoint OldCompanyName.OldServiceName.Configuration.exe is not found.\r\nFileName: D:\\..\\..\\AppType\\..\\OldCompanyName.OldServiceName.ConfigurationServicePkg\\ServiceManifest.xml
```

##### My Question

Does ServiceManifest.xml support having two separate ServiceManifests depending on which build configuration is being used? As an example, my first thought looked something like this (very rough pseudocode):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- IF using old build configuration -->
<ServiceManifest Name="OldServiceName.ConfigurationServicePkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
         This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in Program.cs. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="OldServiceName.Configuration" >
     <PlacementConstraints>requestManagerAllowed==true</PlacementConstraints>
     </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>

  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>OldCompanyName.OldServiceName.Configuration.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value=""/>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </CodePackage>

  <!-- Config package is the contents of the Config directoy under PackageRoot that contains an 
       independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service. -->
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0"/>

</ServiceManifest>

<!-- If using NEW build configuration -->
<ServiceManifest Name="NewServiceName.ConfigurationServicePkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
         This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in Program.cs. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="NewServiceName.Configuration" >
     <PlacementConstraints>requestManagerAllowed==true</PlacementConstraints>
     </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>

  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>NewCompanyName.NewServiceName.Configuration.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value=""/>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </CodePackage>

  <!-- Config package is the contents of the Config directoy under PackageRoot that contains an 
       independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service. -->
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0"/>

</ServiceManifest>
```

Basically, I just need some way for the existing `ServiceManifest.xml` files to conditionally target differently named entry points depending on which build configuration is being used (which environment we are deploying to). Any thoughts for how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a pipeline, (like the [pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/) feature Azure DevOps), you can use a [tokenizer](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) to replace placeholder strings for different environments using variables or variable groups.

You'd create a service manifest template with delimited placeholders (like this `{{key}}`), replace them for the specific build you're running (old or new) and build the package after.

The template would look like this:

```xml
  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>{{companyname}}.Configuration.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
```

Create an Azure DevOps variable named 'companyname', with value 'NewCompanyName.NewServiceName'.

After tokenizing, the file would look like this:

```xml
  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>NewCompanyName.NewServiceName.Configuration.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is a good idea, but unfortunately, we also need to be able to build and publish our service fabric cluster locally, which does not involve using Azure pipelines

Comment: Well, it's feasible to write a [small script](https://gist.github.com/niclaslindstedt/8425dbc5db81b779f3f46659f7232f91) that does this locally right?  You can even [call it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022) from a debug build.

Answer (score 0):

In your service project add a second Service Manifest file (different name with all the changes you need). then edit the service project file:

```
 <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Config2'">
  <None Remove="PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Config1'">
   <None Remove="PackageRoot\OtherServiceManifest.xml" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

In the service fabric application project, add a second application manifest file (that will reference the other service manifest). then edit the project file:

```
   <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Config1'">
     <None Include="ApplicationPackageRoot\ApplicationManifest.xml" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Config2'">
     <None Include="ApplicationPackageRoot\OtherApplicationManifest.xml" />
   </ItemGroup>
```